# Error in calling PHP function in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm stuck in part of my code for calling the php function in Jquery. Here is my code:

```
var remaining_amount= parseFloat(total_amount) - parseFloat(selected_amount);// returns something like 120 
$('.remaining_amount').html('<?php echo display_money('remaining_amount')?>');// here I need to pass it in to my custom PHP function to show the amount with currency.
```

But the problem is that the function `display_money` taking the variable value as string (`remaining_amount`) and creating the problem to produce the desired result. some thing like (120$).

**Updated:**
Here is the full code that show how I'm using the `remaining_amount`, It is changing on the base of selected value.

```
//show the remaining amount 
            $("#selected_amount").live("change", function(event){
                var total_amount=$('#ta').html();
                var selected_amount=$(this).val();
                if(selected_amount=="")
                {
                    $('.remaining_amount_row').hide();
                    $('.final_withdraw').hide();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                var remaining_amount= parseFloat(total_amount) - parseFloat(selected_amount);
                $('.remaining_amount').html(remaining_amount);
                $('.remaining_amount_row').show();
                $('.final_withdraw').show();
                return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: PHP is processed server-side, before the javascript - so your php function `display_money` has no concept of `remaining_amount`. You need to rewrite the `display_money` function in javascript.

Comment: You need to know the difference between [single and double quotes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/1287812)

Comment: You cannot execute a PHP function in javascript.

Comment: Ok seems I need to find another approach for my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use -  **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

```
var remaining_amount= parseFloat(total_amount) - parseFloat(selected_amount);// returns something like 120 
$('.remaining_amount').load('/display_money.php?remaining_amount='+remaining_amount);
```

display_money.php

```
if($_GET['remaining_amount'])
{
 // do the required task
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but value of `remaining amount` is decided at the run time means it is based on `selected_amount` drop down and changes as per the selected value. Another thing is my aim to fix this calculated value to particular place using `.html`. See My updated question.

Comment: ok then why `php` inside the `javascript`? you could also use `javascript` to calculate the `remaining_amount`. and also you should keep the `total_amount` in a hidden field. instead of getting as `html()`.

Comment: Yes that could be the another way to use the java-script function, but i was thought that its better to use function of PHP.

Comment: so you have found the solution or not? i think yes.

Comment: Yes I'm going to use the Java script method for the same functionality having the PHP function.